# Is there such a thing as a "Ruby on Rails gem"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I just discovered the `ruby-on-rails-gems` tag (as opposed to the tags [rubygems](/questions/tagged/rubygems), [gem](/questions/tagged/gem), [bundler](/questions/tagged/bundler), and [ruby-on-rails-plugins](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-plugins)).

Is there such a thing as a "Ruby on Rails gem", as opposed to an ordinary Ruby gem, apart from gems that merely have Rails or one of its components listed as a dependency?

Comment: isn't this supposed to be a meta question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bad tag, it seems like it is mostly used by newbies, and it is usually paired with rubygems (which makes sense). Going through and removing the tags, only 64 questions, so it shouldn't take that long.

EDIT

Done. Not sure how SO works with this, but it doesn't seem to come in up autocomplete anymore. Some questions were literally tagged `ruby-on-rails ruby-on-rails-3 ruby ruby-on-rails-gems ruby-on-rails-plugins`. We need to evangelize the DRY principal when tagging SO posts :)

Answer (score 4):

No, not that i am aware of. There is a rails gem which is basically Rails, aka Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 3):

Gems are packages of Ruby code. Rails itself is a gem, and so is ActiveRecord, ActiveResource, etc etc.

I presume the tag is referring to gems that are compatible with Rails, such as Devise or acts_as_paranoid.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it could be interpreted as "gems that are specifically made to work with Rails". There's plenty of gems which wouldn't work outside of a Rails app. I don't think it's a very useful tag though.